# How to return a redundant row for duplicate ID in single row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, listagg

I have a Audit kind of table where we store some information based on some triggers in other tables.

ID, Changed_Column, OldValue, NewValue will be available.
Now there is a possibility for same Id there will be 3-4 duplicates since the changed column will have different values I wants to merge them into single row and take data
For exmaple,

```
ID   ChangedColumn OldValue NewValue
1    Name           Bob     Roy
1    Age            26      28  
1    Section        B       C
```

When we select now it will display all the rows into separte but I wants to self join and retrieve only one record by merging based on ID value

Expected result is like,

```
ID   Name               Age           Section     ChangedColumns
1    was :Bob now : Roy was:26 now:28 Was:B now:C Name, Age, Section
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to Group the column names you can use `listagg` function.
to convert rows to columns use `Pivot` function.

```
with tab as(
  select 1 as id,    'Name' as col,    'Bob' as OldValue ,     'Roy' as NewValue from dual union all
  select 1 as id,    'Age',            '26',      '28' as NewValue from dual union all  
  select 1 as id,    'Section',        'B',       'C' as NewValue from dual 
)
select * 

from (
select id
      ,t.col as col
      ,max('was: '|| t.OldValue || ' now: ' || t.NewValue) as val
      ,listagg(t.col,',') within group(order by t.id) OVER (PARTITION BY null)  as ChangedColumn 
from tab t
group by id,t.col

) 
pivot ( max(val)  for col in('Name','Age','Section'));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de694207bf1221e95372b7953bffe1a3)*

Comment: Says Col is invalid Identifier, I can understand its not derived anywhere but how to do this mapping in real time is my question

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty simple to do using conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when col = 'Name' then str end) as name,
       max(case when col = 'Age' then str end) as age,
       max(case when col = 'Section' then str end) as section
from (select t.*, ('was: ' || OldValue || ' now: ' || NewValue) as str
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=385d9f180e5db15793471c0844829f3f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: how to map the Column name in real time, (case when col = 'Name' -in this line).
sorry for dumb question but I am new to this

Comment: @RajeshB . . . That requires dynamic SQL and is not the question that you asked here.  If you have a *new* question, ask it as a *new* question, but you may want to investigate "dynamic pivot" before doing so.

Comment: Yes I got it working, by checking the Column which is changed Thanks.