# How to join aggregated data in another table in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, pivot, aggregation

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439988/how-to-return-a-redundant-row-for-duplicate-id-in-single-row-in-oracle) I got some data returned. But again there is a change in my functionality.

I have a source table and another triggered audit  table (when source table is updated Audit table will get updated with old and new values for some of the columns)

So query here is, I needs to take data from source table and when there is a change available in audit table for that particular column I needs to take that value.

Example: FirstName, LastName, Section is there in source table and when there is a update happening then in Audit table new value and old value will be updated.

So in the result set I needs to check the particular Id is there and if there is any changed items I have to return those or else I needs to take data from source table.

SourceTable:

```
ID FirstName LastName Section   Address
1  BOB        A         A       Mississippi
2  ROY        B         B       Edinburgh
```

We change the source value now for bob Section to "B" and Lastname to Andy

```
ID   Link_ID   ChangedColumn OldValue NewValue
1    1         LastName       A       Andy
2    1         Section        B       C
```

now I needs to take the result set of this by checking whether any changed value is there then take that or else take from source table value only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query for fulfilling your requirement:

```
SELECT
    SRC.ID,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN SRC_AUD.CHANGEDCOLUMN = 'FirstName' THEN SRC_AUD.NEWVALUE
        ELSE SRC.FIRSTNAME
    END) AS FIRSTNAME,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN SRC_AUD.CHANGEDCOLUMN = 'LastName' THEN SRC_AUD.NEWVALUE
        ELSE SRC.LASTNAME
    END) AS LASTNAME,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN SRC_AUD.CHANGEDCOLUMN = 'Section' THEN SRC_AUD.NEWVALUE
        ELSE SRC.SECTION
    END) AS SECTION,
    MAX(SRC.ADDRESS) AS ADDRESS
FROM
    SRC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ID,
            LINKID,
            CHANGEDCOLUMN,
            OLDVALUE,
            NEWVALUE
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ID,
                    LINKID,
                    CHANGEDCOLUMN,
                    OLDVALUE,
                    NEWVALUE,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY LINKID, CHANGEDCOLUMN
                        ORDER BY
                            ID DESC NULLS LAST
                    ) AS RN
                FROM
                    SRC_AUD
            )
        WHERE
            RN = 1
    ) SRC_AUD ON SRC.ID = SRC_AUD.LINKID
GROUP BY
    SRC.ID
order by SRC.ID;
```

Hope this is helpful.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8f1cbecb9ec4dc862d7125f702831a5)

Explanation:

1. First, we took the latest changed records from SRC_AUD.
2. Now, we have left joined the above inner view to SRC table and took the value from SRC_AUD, if exists else took the value from original table i.e. SRC

Note: Values in SRC_AUD was stored in multiple rows so we have used group by to take a result in a single row.

Comment: This works fine and I got some idea now. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Explanation would be better, Could you please provide.